# comparying 2 array's with NSPredicate (cocoa)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

i have an NSObject with 2 property's

```
@interface Entity : NSObject  {

     NSNumber *nid;
     NSString *title;
}
```

i have 2 array's with Entity's objects in it  and I want to compare those two on the nid with a predicate

```
array1: ({nid=1,title="test"},{nid=2,title="test2"})
array2: ({nid=2,title="test2"},{nid=3,title="test3"})
```

the 2 arrays have both a nid with value 2 so my output should but

```
array3: ({nid=2,title="test2"})
```

so i can produce an array with only matching nid's

Comment: I have a feeling this was posted incomplete? what do you mean be "matching" nids? and why do you need `NSPredicate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code seems to work for me (it obviously leaks MyEntity objects but that was not the sample target):

```
NSArray* array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[MyEntity alloc] initWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] title:@"1"], 
                   [[MyEntity alloc] initWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] title:@"2"], nil];

NSArray* array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[MyEntity alloc] initWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] title:@"2"], 
                   [[MyEntity alloc] initWithID:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] title:@"3"], nil];

NSArray* idsArray = [array1 valueForKey:@"nid"];
NSArray* filteredArray = [array2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nid IN %@", idsArray]];
```

`filteredArray` contains entities whose ids present in both array.

Comment: NSArray* idsArray = [array1 valueForKey:@"nid"]; doesn't work,  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSDecimalNumber 0x4e679f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nid.'

Comment: That must mean that some objects in your array are not MyEntity objects or were corrupted somehow...

Comment: all my objects are entity objects and i don't know how they can be corrupted because when i log nid it shows up perfectly

Comment: So you've tried iterating through your array and call nid on each element? May be you could post more code where you create and fill your array... Error message shows that NSDecimalNumber object receives nid message for some reason - that must imply that it is in your array

Comment: it (finally) works, do have any idea to the opposite ? to get all the objects from array 1 that doesn't match any nid in array2 ?